# How to add another parameter to $.param()?

Tags: jquery

I'm passing my data through Ajax with `$.param()`, but now I want to add another parameter to that data.

Is there a way to merge `$.param(myData)` with `{ action: 'updateMyData' }`?

```
$.ajax({
    type     : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    url      : urlSettingsAction,
    data     : $.param(myData) + { action: 'updateMyData' }  // Something like this
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery, use $.extend() method.

```
data     : $.param($.extend(myData,{ action: 'updateMyData' } ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myDate={
    param1= value,
    param2=value
};
```

And then use

```
$.ajax({
    type     : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    url      : urlSettingsAction,
    data     : $.param(myData) + { action: 'updateMyData' }  // Something like this
});
```